# Adding methods to a default class

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking to add a .owner and .number method to the UIButton class. I need to assign each individual number an (int)number so that I can use numbers to separate the buttons.

e.g so I could write `buttonName.number = 1` and `buttonName.owner = @"Player1";`

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do this thing. The easier one is to subclass the UIButton class and add the properties as you needed which could be achieved as;

```
@interface MyButton:UIButton
@property(nonatomic, assign) int number;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *owner
@end
```

And the other way is to use runtime to add properties into the class. For this you would create a category for the class and then add property into the interface and then add properties to it using the runtime as;

```
@interface UIButton(MyCategory)
@property(nonatomic, assign) float number;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *owner;
@end

@implementation UIButton(MYCategory)
NSString *const numberKey = @"kNumberKey";
NSString *const ownerKey = @"kOwnerKey";

 - (float)number{ 
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &numberKey) floatValue]; 
 } 

-(void)setNumber:(float)num{ 
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &numberKey,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}

-(NSString*)owner{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ownerKey);
}

-(void)setOwner:(NSString *)own{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ownerKey, own, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

@end
```

With this you will be able to add the custom properties to the UIButton class itself.

Comment: I made a category called UIButton and its a category of UIButton. I put the interface and implementation in there and get `use of undeclared identifier 'number' and 'owner'`

Comment: Make sure you have made correct imports for this. Use #import <objc/runtime.h>. Sorry I have missed something here. See my edits.

Comment: Well see it now. It should work. I was making some mistake myself instead of using the key and the value passed in methods, I was using something else.

Comment: Sorry, I was not checking the error in the code. But the edited code above is working implementation.

Comment: Thank you, it works but I'm having some problems with the number. Getting a conflicting return and parameter types for 'number' - 'int' vs 'NSNumber'. Compiles fine but when the button loads the program crashes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20017/discussion-between-sina-yamani-and-insane-36)